# Referencing outer criteria query aliases from within an SQLProjection

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am aware that you can use `{alias}` to refer to the root entity within an SQLProjection:

```
Projections.sqlProjection("MIN({alias}.field) as value", new String[]{"value"}, new Type[]{new LongType()}))
```

What I am trying to do is to reference an alias for a *non-root* entity:

```
Projections.sqlProjection("MIN(i.powerRestarts) as value", new String[]{"value"}, new Type[]{new LongType()}))
```

where `i` is an alias from the outer criteria query. The code above throws an SQL exception saying that `i.powerRestarts` cannot be found.

Is it possible to refer to a non-root alias from an SQLProjection?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Having done some googling, it appears that this this is not possible - Hibernate only allows inclusion of the root entity alias using `{alias}` in the SQL string of the `SQLProjection`. I did however find [this issue regarding the limitation](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2952) on the Hibernate JIRA pages.

Someone has kindly submitted a patch that allows the use of non-root aliases in the `SQLProjection` string, through a new `RestrictionsExt` class. Using my example from the question:

```
Projections.sqlProjection("MIN(i.powerRestarts) as value", new String[]{"value"}, new Type[]{new LongType()}))
```

The alias `i` can now be referenced as:

```
RestrictionsExt.sqlProjection("MIN({i}.powerRestarts) as value", "value", new LongType())
```

I had to modify the static `RestrictionsExt.sqlProjection` method to allow specification of the type for the column alias (`"value"`) (here defined as `LongType`), as the patch didn't allow this and defaulted to `StringType`.

The SQLAliasedProjection class in the patch also requires access to the following private methods in `org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator`: `getOuterQueryTranslator` and `getAliasedCriteria`. To get this to work without modifying the Hibernate source, I used reflection:

```
cri = ((org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator) criteriaQuery).getAliasedCriteria(alias);
```

was changed to:

```
Method m = ((org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator) criteriaQuery).getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getAliasedCriteria", String.class);
m.setAccessible(true);
cri = (Criteria) m.invoke(((org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator) criteriaQuery), alias);
```

Hopefully this will help anyone else facing the same problem.

Comment: what is your hibernate version ?